# What is the purpose of a CORS whitelist?

Tags: node.js, http, https, cors, phishing

I have a GraphQL API that has CORS enabled and I have an array of valid origins, urls where client side requests can make requests to the API.

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://example.com"],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}))
```

What is the real purpose of blocking origins? Because this is an API any server can talk directly to this API. This really only prevents / limits clients from accessing the API.

If it's important at all to actually have a real whitelist, my question is should I allow `http` protocols, because `http` protocols can be easily spoofed / phished.

1. What's the main downside or security venerability for allowing any origin (`*`) to a CORS enabled API?
2. Should a CORS whitelist domain ever support `http` origins?

Comment: I like to see CORS origin blocking as an extra layer of security for your API when you want only specific clients accessing it

Comment: @Daniel so would you only whitelist `https` domains?

Comment: The main point of CORS is not to block a specific protocol, is to block unwanted clients

Comment: @Daniel Do unwanted clients include phishing sites pretending to be you? Because it if is then you need to specify `https` no?

Comment: Even if you specify HTTPS, clients could still send a request over HTTPS to your API and spoof the origin. You shouldn't rely on CORS as the only layer of security, use cookies or OAuth tokens or something other than the Origin header to secure properly your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your first question**, When you use the * you are allowing anyone one and every website to make request to your API.

**For your second question** use your own discretion but ask your self:
  Will there be a lot of traffic on your website?
  Why would someone want access to my API?
  Do i have any routes that can cause harm to myself/company?