# how to post data from an ionic App to Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to send data to a google cloud function from an ionic app and I keep getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/upload_data' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

even when removing the request header the same error is displayed.
a little help will be appreciated, thank you.

my typescript code:

```
var httpheader = new HttpHeaders();
    
    httpheader.append('Accept','application/json');
    httpheader.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  
     let data = {"testbody":"this is test data"};
      
      await this.http.post('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/upload_data',data
      ,{headers:httpheader}).subscribe((resp)=>{
          console.log(resp);   
        });
```

python cloud function:

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headrs':'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age':'3600'
        }
        return ('',204,headers)
    headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
    
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args
    
    if request_json and 'testbody' in request_json:
        testname = request_json['testbody']
    elif request_args and 'testbody' in request_args:
        testname = request_args['testbody']
    else:
        testname = 'Nothing sent'
    return (jsonify(testname),200,headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CORS` related configuration needs to be done in the `server side` code. From your question, I see that you are using the `Flask` framework in `Python`. So you need to configure `CORS` in Flask as follows:

Install **flask-cors** by running -

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

Consider following sample endpoint code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

**UPDATE**

In `Production` environment, please `refrain` from using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'`. Instead you should `whitelist` your domain. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426802/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-cors-whitelist) and [here](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/enterprise/configuring-infrastructure/whitelist-application-cors).

Also if you are using `Ionic with Capacitor` I would suggest using the [Http plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http). If possible, you can also write your own `custom plugin` to implement a **network** call `natively` using the underlying OS `platform-specific` API's as this would prevent any CORS related issue from occuring.

Reference links:

[Flask CORS configuration](http://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

[Allow CORS for Flask endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517054/allow-cors-to-flask-endpoint)

Comment: the headers are as documented by google, no need to add flask cors, but the problem is now solved when I imported flask request library. any way thanks for the answer

Comment: sorry bro it did not , the porblem was that I forgot to import the request library